# How to make rating bar non clickable in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to make default flutter ratingbar non clickable ?

I have to disable rating option once user give feedback. How do I do it.

```dart
 RatingBar(
  itemSize: 35,
  initialRating: 0,
  glowColor: Colors.transparent,
  direction: Axis.horizontal,
  allowHalfRating: false,
  tapOnlyMode: false,
  itemCount: 5,
  itemPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
  ratingWidget: RatingWidget(
    full: Image.asset(img_star_rating_fill, width: 25.w, height: 25.h),
    // full: const Icon(Icons.star, color:yellow_FFC800),
    half: Image.asset(img_star_rating_fill, width: 25.w, height: 25.h),
    // half: const Icon(Icons.star_half, color:yellow_FFC800,),
    empty:
        Image.asset(img_star_rating_empty, width: 25.w, height: 25.h),
  ),
  // empty: const Icon(Icons.star_outline, color:gray_868590,)),
  onRatingUpdate: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _ratingValue = value;

      printData(
          'Rating to consultation booking ID', _ratingValue.toString());
      controller
          .callRateConsultationAPI(
              widget.i,
              controller.pastBookingList[widget.i].id.toString(),
              value.toString())
          .then((value) {
        setState(() {
          // ratingBar.setFocusable(false);
        });
      });
    });
  })
```

Comment: could you add your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `ignoreGestures` to `true`, like this:

```
RatingBar(
    ignoreGestures: true, // <---- add this
    itemSize: 35,
    initialRating:0,
    glowColor: Colors.transparent,
    direction: Axis.horizontal,
    allowHalfRating: false,
   ...
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
IgnorePointer(child:RatingWidget)
```

Comment: This works, but it is not the best idea.